# Need help adding caption with arrow over a div on mouseover event

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-interface, hover

Regarding the hover effect, pelase check the site http://www.rokivo.com/

i want such a effect to be include for headings,buttons and div in mysite.

thanks in advance

```
<div class="col-xs-12"> <a href="enquiry.html"><h3 class="orange2 pull-right contact-head">ENQUIRY<br/><i class="fa fa-arrow-right black arrow4 pull-left"></i></h3></a> </div>
```

i used jquery to add css transition class on mouseenter and remove that class on mouseleave but it looks odd. i want similar effect in the referral url above.

Comment: show what you have in a snippet

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNEzwm   sir here is the link i put my part of the code , it works fine but in codepen its not working.

Comment: on hover the heading a arrow will slide infintely but all i need is a single transition effect with the long arrow as in rokivo.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you didn't want to have the arrow sliding infinitely so I removed `infinite` also I added the longer arrow (`fa-long-arrow-right`) since you mentioned the "long arrow" in the comments.

I also added `forwards` so the arrow will stay at the end position of the animation and not go back to the beginning. This is the [animation-fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)

```css
.contact-head{
 font-size:17px !important;
 padding:15px !important;
 border:2px solid #555 !important;
 border-bottom:5px solid #ffc000 !important;
 min-width:270px;
 max-width:270px;
}


@-webkit-keyframes arrow-jump3 {
  0%   { opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(25px);
        -moz-transform: translateX(25px);
        -0-transform: translateX(25px);
        transform: translateX(25px);
  }
  100% { opacity: 1;  
        -webkit-transform: translateX(160px);
        -moz-transform: translateX(160px);
        -0-transform: translateX(160px);
        transform: translateX(160px);
    } 
}
.arrow4 {
  -webkit-animation: arrow-jump3 1s forwards; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    arrow-jump3 1s forwards; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      arrow-jump3 1s forwards; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         arrow-jump3 1s forwards; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
 
}
.contact-head i{
  display:none;
}
.contact-head:hover > i{
margin-top:10px; 
display:block;
} 
.contact-head:hover{
 background:#ffc000 !important;
 color:#000 !important;
 border-bottom:2px solid #555 !important;
}

.contact h3{
 margin:20px 0px 20px 0px;
 font-size:19px;
}
a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-xs-12"> <a href="enquiry.html"><h3 class="orange2 pull-right contact-head">ENQUIRY<br/><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right black arrow4 pull-left"></i></h3></a> </div>
 <div class="col-xs-12"> <a href="servicecall.html"><h3 class="orange2 pull-right contact-head">REGISTER SERVICE CALL<br/><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right black arrow4 pull-left"></i></h3></a> </div>
 <div class="col-xs-12"> <a href="feedback.html"><h3 class="orange2 pull-right contact-head">CUSTOMER FEEDBACK<br/><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right black arrow4 pull-left"></i></h3></a> </div>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/JackSchuldenfrei/pen/NNPwMR)

Hope this helps. Good luck.

PS. Your codepen (arrow) wasn't working because you didn't include the font awesome css. You got to click on the cog icon and include your externals there.

---

Since you asked for me to look at the website I tried to do it the way  I saw it. You might have to tweek it a little bit for your needs but for the most part it should give you an idea of how to accomplish your goal. I didn't feel that there was a need to use `keyframes` so I used simple transitions on hover. when you hover over a parent you can also target a child and have that child transition. Hope you understand.

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.box{
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #eee;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #45ca58;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  margin: 0 auto; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
.border{
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #45ca58;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -40px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
/*on hover target the border element so that should move*/
.box:hover > .border{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
.arrow{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left:-20px;
  color:white;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.box:hover > .arrow{
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class = "box">
  <span class = "border"></span>
  <span class="arrow"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot and i achieved one time animation as you told and i need the longer arrow as in referral url. somehow i get code using chrome developer tool.

Comment: `fa-long-arrow-right` is the longest arrow   https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZEpbe  here the codepen link i attached the arrow and now i dont want my div height to collapse on hover. instead the arrow should display within the fixed height of the div.    if you know what logic they used to draw an arrow can you please describe me, am not familiar with before after codes...

Comment: please refer rokivo.com

Comment: I added an edit about how i would do the arrow effect in  a timely manner.

Comment: ok I'll tell you what the `after` is/ The ::after selector inserts something after the content of each selected element in the case of rokivo.com it is the arrow. BTW. they made the arrow with css and not font awesome. in my updated answer I used box and in rokivo they uses an an `li class="card"`  and instead of me using `after` I used a child el(.arrow) and positioned that out view with overflow hidden. `li class="card"` is also oveflow hidden

Comment: i cant get you completely but somehow i understood your code a little.

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear. rokivo uses `::after`. when you use `::after` it's like creating an element on the page. It's not like a regular element you don't see the content in the DOM. but its good for displaying design element on the screen like arrows. you attach the `::after` (pseudo elements) to a parent like `li class="card"` and the pseudo element will act like a child to the  `li` ex:  `li.card::after{content : "", display : block}`  great article https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/  dont forget to choose an answer